# why java fx 2.0 is not on the diagram of the java platform?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I was looking at the diagram of the java platform for java SE

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/index.html

Why is it that java fx is not there? I thought java fx is replacing swing and so it should be in this diagram.

May be the diagram has not been updated? where would you put java fx 2.0 in this diagram? next to the swing block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at this - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/index.html - you will see that Java FX is not a part of the Standard Edition. Its a separate entity.

The diagram that you have specified is that of Java SE.